# How to get Facebook page news feed on website

Tags: facebook, feed

Alright, So I am making a website that will have groups of pages, on those pages it will have the ability for a user to paste a Facebook page URL. How would I go about using their API to retrieve that pages news feed? It baffles me that Facebook expects everyone to know how to use it. I am new to this whole API thing and the documentation is not very clear. Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: Need a little more information like what language, PHP, Javascript etc?

Comment: What URL do you intend on allowing a user to paste in?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook reports that plugin's deprecated, use `Page` instead:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin
```

Answer (score -1):

This link provides all the information you should need?

Simply follow the steps, then use Get Code, you can then adapt the code to use the URLs your users input.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages/

Comment: He is after the feed, not a like-box